# Ember unable to find template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to render a view dynamically in Ember.js

```
Resume.ItemView = Em.View.create({
  click: function(){
    var view = Em.View.create({
      templateName: 'my_exp'});
    view.append();
  },  
});
```

I have in /templates my_exp.hbs

But get

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You specified the templateName my_exp for <Ember.View:ember261>, but it did not exist.
```

Is there a better approach for trying to do this? Can anyone suggest resources?

Comment: if you go to console and type `Ember.TEMPLATES`, do you see your template in the collection?

Comment: yes:
Ember.TEMPLATES;
Object {application: function,... my_exp: function…}

Comment: That my friend... worked.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

A recent update to Ember removed the defaultContainer for looking up templates.
For people manually creating views this has created some issues.

To achieve what you want you need to use `createChildView`.

```
Resume.ItemView = Em.View.create({
  click: function(){
    var view = this.createChildView(Ember.View, {
      templateName: 'my_exp'
    });
    view.append();
  },  
});
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/Uyt5p/))

Comment: Thanks for responding. Now i get
 
    Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You must pass instance or subclass of View

Comment: Whoops, fixed now, you need to pass a view class to instantiate from